# Update value in Array which has pattern in Java

Tags: java, json

I have an array which has pattern `[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]`.

I want to update `value2` in the above array.

Please suggest how to proceed using `Java`.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use a `JSONParser` and set the value for `key2`

Comment: @UmaKanth Thanks for the reply. I don't know how to use JSONParser for array which has key value pair.

Comment: That "pattern" is [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. Use a JSON parser to parse it, then change the value, and use a JSON formatter to convert it back to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html)** and **[JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)** to parse your json array from your string, and change the value of `value2` using its key `key2`:

```
JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.readFrom("[{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}]");
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
   JSONObject jo=jsonArray.get(i);
   if(jo.has("key2")) {
      jo.remove("key2");
      jo.put("key2", "new value");
   }
}
```

And finally change it back to `String` json:

```
String changedJSON = jsonArray.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]");

String[] keys = JSONObject.getNames(object);

for (String key : keys)
{
    if(key.equals("key2")){
       object.put(key, "new value");
    }
}
```